# Remove back slashes from JSON response

Tags: javascript

I am getting the JSON error response from server in the following way,

```
let err = {
        "_body": "{\"error\":\"264\",\"message\":\"Please enter valid usename/password\",\"object\":null}",
        "status": 400,
        "ok": false
    }
```

And i want to display the error message on the screen '**Please enter valid usename/password**'

I tried in the following way but no luck,

```
console.log((this.err._body).replace(/\\/g, ''));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to deserialize the body.

```js
let err = {
        "_body": "{\"error\":\"264\",\"message\":\"Please enter valid usename/password\",\"object\":null}",
        "status": 400,
        "ok": false
    }

var body = JSON.parse(err._body);
console.log(body.message);
```

Click on `Run code snippet` to see this working.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to decode the wrapped json string again:

```
let responseBody = JSON.parse(this.err._body);
console.log(responseBody.message);
```